# How would I go up a directory in lua?

Tags: lua

Let's say I have a root folder like this:

```
--+ Folder 
  +-+ OtherFolder
  | +-- main.lua
  +-+ AnotherFolder
    +-- output.txt
```

And I want main.lua to use `io.output()` and set the .txt file to be in the "AnotherFolder" folder. What would I do?

I've tried using `io.output(";../AnotherFolder/output.txt)` and `io.output("../AnotherFolder/output.txt)` however they give me the "no such file or directory" error (The file does exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file path is relative to the directory you run the script from.

For example imagine I have a directory layout like this:

```
foo/
  bar/
    main.lua
  baz/
    file.txt
```

and my main.lua looks like this

```
io.output('../baz/file.txt')
io.write('Hello World!')
```

If I run the program from the `bar` directory it works, but if I run it from the `foo` directory you get

`cannot open file '../baz/file.txt' (No such file or directory)`

You would need to change the file path to `baz/file.txt` to make it work from that directory.

Comment: That's weird, I'm running my program from bar, however it could be that because I'm using love2d, I drag `bar` to love.exe (Wich is in `foo`), if I use require() it looks inside `bar` tho?